# Prove that the norm on the space of real-valued Lipschitz functions is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the space of real-valued Lipschitz functions of order 1 defined on $[0,1]$. That is, the class of functions $f$ such that
$$
\sup\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1], x\neq y}
\dfrac{\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert}{\vert x-y\vert}
=K(f)<\infty.
$$
Let $\Vert f\Vert_1=\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +K(f)=\Vert f\Vert + K(f)$.
Show that $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ is a norm on $\mathcal{L}$.

To show $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ is a norm on $\mathcal{L}$, I use 3 axioms of definition of norm.

Take $f,g\in \mathcal{L}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

(1)
\begin{align*}
\Vert f+g\Vert_1=
\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)+g(t)\vert +K(f+g)
&\leq \sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert g(t)\vert +K(f)+K(g)\\
&= \left(\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert + K(f)\right) + \left(\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert g(t)\vert + K(g)\right)\\
&=\Vert f\Vert_1+\Vert g\Vert_1
\end{align*}

(2)
\begin{align*}
\Vert af\Vert_1=
\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert af(t)\vert +K(af)
&= a\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +aK(f)\\
&\leq \vert a\vert \sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +\vert a\vert K(f)\\
&= \vert a\vert \left(\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +K(f)\right)\\
&= \vert a\vert \Vert f\Vert_1\\
\end{align*}

(3)
If
\begin{align*}
\Vert f\Vert_1=
\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert +K(f) = 0
\end{align*}
then we will prove $f=0$.

\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\vert f(t)\vert  &= -K(f)\\
&= -\sup\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1], x\neq y}
\dfrac{\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert}{\vert x-y\vert}.
\end{align*}

In this case, I don't know how to get $f=0$.

**My question**

Does my proof in (1) and (2) correct? In (3), how to get $f=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of 1) and 2) are correct. For 3) you are over-thinking. Sum of two non-negative numbers cannot be $0$ unless they are both zero. Hence $\|f\|_1=0$ implies $\sup|f(t)|=0$ so $f(t)=0$ for all $t$.